# Pre-incrementing a string literal

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

§ 2.14.5/8 of the N3337 draft standard states:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and has static storage duration (3.7).

§ 4.2

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.

I expected `++"hello world!"` to decay `"hello world!"` to a `char*` but this does not happen. It must be forced using an extra plus, `+++"hello world!"`. There are some cases where the array-to-pointer conversion is not applied, such as the `sizeof` operator.

§ 5.3.2 simply says:

> The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it
>   is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable
>   lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a
>   pointer to a completely-defined object type. The result is the updated
>   operand; it is an lvalue, and it is a bit-field if the operand is a
>   bit-field. If x is not of type bool, the expression ++x is equivalent
>   to x+=1

So why doesn't this conversion happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array-to-pointer (and other decay) conversions are applied when it's necessary to convert a glvalue to a prvalue, as per 5/8:

> Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand,
>   the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), or function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are applied
>   to convert the expression to a prvalue.

Notice that by your own quoting of 5.3.2, the operand of `++` must be a modifiable lvalue. The array-to-pointer conversion is used to turn a glvalue into a prvalue, which is NOT what `++` needs. Therefore, nothing calls for the array-to-pointer conversion. It would actually be invalid to apply it, as the result of that conversion is a prvalue, on which `++` can not act.